# read and unread messages status in react chat application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, websocket

I am working on react chat application and want to show the message status wether it is "sent" and if user has seen the message, want to update the message status as "read". But the problem is, the updated state is not showing in another browser tab/window.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ChatInput from './ChatInput'
import ChatMessage from './ChatMessage'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'
import Header from './Header'
import $ from 'jquery'

const URL = 'ws://localhost:3030'

class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: props.loginData.username?props.loginData.username:sessionStorage.getItem("userName"),
      toUserName: props.loginData.toUser,
      messages: [],
      userdata: [],
      receiveUser:"",
      readmsg:false,
      updateMsg:false
    }
    this.refreshMessages = this.refreshMessages.bind(this)
  }

  ws = new WebSocket(URL)

  componentDidMount() {

    this.ws.onopen = () => {

      // On connecting, do nothing but log it to the console
    }

    this.ws.onmessage = () => {

      // On receiving a message, add it to the list of messages
      // alert("new message received")
      const userchat = {
        userId: sessionStorage.getItem("userId"),
        chatId: sessionStorage.getItem("chatId")
      }
      fetch('/getmessages', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(userchat),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({
            userdata: data
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error, with message::", error)
        });
    }

    this.ws.onclose = () => {

      // Automatically try to reconnect on connection loss
      this.setState({
        ws: new WebSocket(URL),
      })
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newprops) {
    this.setState({
      toUserName: newprops.loginData.toUser
    })
  }

  addMessage = message =>{
    this.setState(state => ({ messages: [message, ...state.messages] 
    })
  )}

  submitMessage = messageString => {
    $(".chat-room").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
    // on submitting the ChatInput form, send the message, add it to the list and reset the input
    const message = {
      name: this.state.name,
      message: messageString,
      toUser: this.state.toUserName,
      userId: sessionStorage.getItem("userId"),
      chatId: sessionStorage.getItem("chatId")
    }
    this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(message))

    //api call using fetch
    fetch('/chat', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(message),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.refreshMessages()
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error, with message::", error)
      });
  }

  refreshMessages() {
    const userchat = {
      userId: sessionStorage.getItem("userId"),
      chatId: sessionStorage.getItem("chatId")
    }
    fetch('/getmessages', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(userchat),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          userdata: data,
          readmsg:false
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error, with message::", error)
      });
  }

  onSendUserChat(msgData) {
    this.setState({
      userdata: msgData
    },()=>{    
      setTimeout( () => {
        this.setState({
        readmsg: true
      });
    }, 2000);
    })
  }

  receiveUserName(name){
    this.setState({
      receiveUser:name
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("userName") != null) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header name={this.state.name} id={sessionStorage.getItem("userId")} sendUserName={this.receiveUserName.bind(this)} />
        <div id="chatContainer" >
          <Sidebar sendUserchat={this.onSendUserChat.bind(this)} receiveUser={this.state.receiveUser} updateMsg={this.state.updateMsg} />
            <section id="main">
            <div className="chat-room" id="main-chat">
            {
              this.state.userdata.map((msg, index) => {
                return (
                  <p> <strong>{msg.userName}:&nbsp;</strong> <em> {msg.message}</em><div className="read-msg">{msg.read===false?"sent":"read"}</div></p>
              />
                )
              })
            }
            </div>
            <ChatInput
              ws={this.ws}
              onSubmitMessage={messageString => this.submitMessage(messageString)}
            />
          </section>          
        </div>
      </div>
    )
   }
   else{
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
   }
  }
}

// Connect redux state
export default withRouter(connect((state) => ({ loginData: state.chat.loginData }))(Chat));
```

How to update the state value in both the windows or browser tabs regarding the chat application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

State is something local to a particular session. Every session will have its own state.

What you want to achieve can only be sent to server from First session.

Retrieve from server in the next sessions and change the state on the second session.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75220565/how-to-do-when-msg-is-readed-then-color-is-change-or-msg-is-nor-read-its-color